# Dependency jar not loading its own resource file

Tags: java, properties, jar, build, gradle

I have a dependency `utilities.jar` which has a `dev.properties` file in the root directory when compiled (in `src/main/resources` when uncompiled). The jar has a class (`PropertiesUtil.java`) that loads the properties with:

```
PropertiesUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/dev.properties");
```

This jar is included as a dependency in my webapp. The webapp has its own dev.properties file in its root directory when compiled (in uncompiled form its in the `src/main/resources` folder).

The utilities.jar does not load its own internal `dev.properties` file but instead the webapp's `dev.properties` file.

I tried different methods like

```
PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("dev.properties");
```

without success.

I am using Gradle to compile the `utilities.jar` and the webapp into a war. The properties filename need to be the same because I pass in a JVM property

```
-Dproperty.filename=[dev|qa|prd].properties
```

when starting up the webapp. This system property is used to load the correct properties files for the webapp and the `utilities.jar`.

The utilities.jar is a separate project and packaged with `gradle clean build` and uploaded to an artifact server. The webapp pulls the `utilities.jar` from the artifact server when building the war.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you also [edit] it to include a gradle snippet?

Comment: @durron597 i don't think that would make a difference. the build.gradle files are straight forward...

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there are two copies of `/dev.properties` in your jar or if one is getting overwritten. But I have an idea, see incoming answer

Comment: @durron597oh i see. the utilities.jar has its own dev.properties packaged into it at the root of its own package... the webapp is packaged with its own dev.properties at the WEB-INF/classes/ (when it is unexploded)

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is occurring because you have two different files with exactly the same path (even though one is inside a jar) inside your classpath. It's very possible one `dev.properties` is getting overwritten.

I recommend changing the path of at least one of the properties files to be outside of the project root. For example, put the uncompiled `dev.properties` for Utilities at:

```
/src/main/resources/utilities/dev.properties
```

Then access it with:

```
PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/utilities/dev.properties");
```

Then the two properties files won't stomp on each other anymore, and that should fix your problem.